# How to extend image beyond edges of top bar?

Tags: ios, swift

Please see attached. As you can see there's a lot of white space at the top of the iphone. Is there a way to extend the image that you see above the white space?

[image]

Comment: You can constraint it  directly to `view`, instead of `safeAreaLayoutGuide`.

Comment: Please note that this is not "white space". It is the status bar; it has content. Do not do anything to mar the legibility of that content by putting noisy imagery behind it.

Comment: @Rob what does that mean?

Comment: You can google it, go to Apple's website and you will find the detailed explanation. It is the area which contains the space for status bar as simple as that. One more piece of suggestion, try running the same in iPhone 8 or a phone without notch and see if the safeArea still bugs you.

Comment: can you share your constraints ?

Comment: @jawadAli SuperView. I'm using the main story board

Comment: i got that ... but you gave your imageView some constraints ... i am talking about them

Answer (score 0):

1.To image add top space constraint to superView not with safe area

2.select image and go to attribute inspector & set content mode "Scale to Fill"

this will cover your top blank space area with image.